# Youtube Player won't start upon setTimeout, help needed

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, settimeout

I have followed the Youtube API while constructing a player. I need to to call the autoplay function via javascript but it won't listen to the setTimeout function, and it won't start playing:

Could someone light me up where am I wrong?

Regards!

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
       events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      }

    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event){
  setTimeout(function(){

  playVideo();

  },5000);

  }
```

Comment: Are you getting any client side errors? Is your onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() function being hit? And is "YT" actually an object at this point?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have changed playVideo(); to player.playVideo(); and now it is ok.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

As you are declaring `player` variable and later set it to instance of `YT.Player`, you have to use the same variable on `setTimeout` too.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    player.playVideo();
},5000);
```